# How to center align the title in a JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, titlebar

I have a **JFrame with a Title**. I want **center align the title**, so that it appears in the **middle of the JFrame's title**.

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Consider leaving the title left-justified...but...this will get you near the center.  For resizable frames, you need to rewrite the title on resize.

```
JFrame t = new JFrame();
t.setSize(600,300);
t.setFont(new Font("System", Font.PLAIN, 14));
Font f = t.getFont();
FontMetrics fm = t.getFontMetrics(f);
int x = fm.stringWidth("Hello Center");
int y = fm.stringWidth(" ");
int z = t.getWidth()/2 - (x/2);
int w = z/y;
String pad ="";
//for (int i=0; i!=w; i++) pad +=" "; 
pad = String.format("%"+w+"s", pad);
t.setTitle(pad+"Hello Center");
```

Comment: +1, I guess that's the right answer, but for resizable from I guess he can write one `addWindowStateListener(...)` to make that work :-)

Answer (score 8):

Adapting the [answer's source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9662974/5524514) of @Java42, I did a "workaround" to adjust title when resizing JFrame:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.event.ComponentAdapter;
import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;


public class JFrameTitleCenter {

    public void createAndShowGUI() {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 200));
        frame.setTitle("Hello Center");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
                titleAlign(frame);
            }

        });

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    private void titleAlign(JFrame frame) {

        Font font = frame.getFont();

        String currentTitle = frame.getTitle().trim();
        FontMetrics fm = frame.getFontMetrics(font);
        int frameWidth = frame.getWidth();
        int titleWidth = fm.stringWidth(currentTitle);
        int spaceWidth = fm.stringWidth(" ");
        int centerPos = (frameWidth / 2) - (titleWidth / 2);
        int spaceCount = centerPos / spaceWidth;
        String pad = "";
        pad = String.format("%" + (spaceCount - 14) + "s", pad);
        frame.setTitle(pad + currentTitle);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            new JFrameTitleCenter().createAndShowGUI();
        });
    }
}
```

Working:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
I have a JFrame with a Title. I want center align the title, so that 
it appears in the middle of the JFrame's title.
```

simple not possible to centering narrarive in the `JFrames TitleBar`, this container came from `Native OS`

- dirty hack are possible by implements `getSystemLookAndFeel` in Windows OS
- create undecorated `JFrame` by adding `JPanel` (simulated `Toolbar`) with JButtons (JButtons with icons simulating standards buttons )

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that you can without using a complicated scheme. If it's to your liking, you could apply a titled border with centered text to the frame's content pane.

Answer (score 0):

center align the title in a jFrame is very easy in netbeans, what u need to do is below:

1.

[image]

2.

[image]

3. run your app.

[image]