# How can i set defaultlookandfeel to window for Jframe

Tags: java, swing, jframe, look-and-feel

I made a simple Jframe with its child components in netbeans, when i run the application it shows it in NIMBUZZ lookandfeel as shown below:-

[image: This is what i have]

But I want it to be always shown in WINDOWS lookandfeel as shown below :-

[image: This is what i want]

How am I suppose to do that??

Comment: use renderer for JFrame

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before creating your **first** window call this code:

```
UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
```

note that this will work as expected only under windows where this is the system LAF

Comment: @Sushantp606, would you care to say what was the problem?

Comment: Actually the frame is fine , i changed lookandfeel in Main method of Jframe class in netbeans . When i run it , the window means frame appears but in nimbuzz lookandfeel , intead of that i want widows look and feel . The thing you mentioned in your answer is an better option but its showing error. So where exactly i shall implement this line of code?

Comment: @Sushantp606 you need to call it in the main method before any invockation of Swing related code - also note that there are several exceptions to catch you can just log them or try a different LAF if an exception is thrown

Comment: thanks , Last thing if i run this app on linux , will it work??

Comment: It will work but the LAF will not be the one for windows as windows LAF only available on windows OS

Comment: So it will automatically use GTK+ or motif , based on OS theme?

Answer (score 2):

You maybe looking for [`setWindowDecorationStyle()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JRootPane.html#setWindowDecorationStyle%28int%29), although some L&Fs may not support the feature. A complete example is cited [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19923308/230513).