# How to center my Text on the JTitleBar in java?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, titlebar

I code:

```
JFrame j = new JFrame("Hospital Management System");
```

but when I maximize the form the text on the TitleBar is move to the right, so I want the text always at the center.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm assuming you mean on a `JFrame`?  Then no, it can't be done...

Comment: Check this

[Already answered here]


  : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9662393/how-to-center-align-the-title-in-a-jframe

Comment: You have to provide more details (e.g. code snippets, screenshots) and improve your question tags. I'm not sure anybody could understand the problem you're facing for now.

Comment: @Stunner Good one! But I think there should also be a Listener for the window size, to keep the title centered

Comment: @BackSlash. Yes,there should be a listener.

Comment: Thank for your support BackSlash! Now I fixed it. And I want to ask you another question, I want to control the form load in Netbeans, I mean that I want to load the Login Form First and then Main Form. Can you tell me about this issue?