# center align the title in JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, titlebar

I want to know how to center the JFrame title.I referred following link 
[How to center align the title in a JFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9662393/how-to-center-align-the-title-in-a-jframe)

but I need to center title  without putting spacing.

Comment: It's unlikely that you can effect the title position of natively supplied frame borders, about the only other solution you have is to provide your own look and feel frame decoration

Comment: Why subject the user to a GUI that breaks the pattern of *every* other app. on their PC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider leaving the title left-justified...but...this will get you near the center. For resizable frames, you need to rewrite the title on resize.

```
JFrame t = new JFrame();
t.setSize(600,300);
t.setFont(new Font("System", Font.PLAIN, 14));
Font f = t.getFont();
FontMetrics fm = t.getFontMetrics(f);
int x = fm.stringWidth("Hello Center");
int y = fm.stringWidth(" ");
int z = t.getWidth()/2 - (x/2);
int w = z/y;
String pad ="";
//for (int i=0; i!=w; i++) pad +=" "; 
pad = String.format("%"+w+"s", pad);
t.setTitle(pad+"Hello Center");
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9662974/3675925

Answer (score 1):

Thats the only way to do it in Swing. Take note that adding spaces to center the window's title will affect other platforms. For example, for Windows 7 the title is displayed on the top-left, however on Windows 8 the title will be displayed on the top-center. Unless you want to specifically check what OS the client is running, I suggest just leaving the title as it is.