# How to set the title of the app in the center of the title bar?

Tags: java, swing, titlebar

I see many applications which show the title of the application at the center of the title bar. Even Intellij and Visual studio code has set the title at the center of the title bar.

Is there anyway that I can achieve that using `javax.swing`

I tried by checking the window width and adding that many spaces at the beginning of the title (removing helf of the text size also). But in the result I don't see the spaces I added at the beginning.

Is there any other way that I can do that?

Comment: See if this helps : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9662393/how-to-center-align-the-title-in-a-jframe

Comment: Yes I tried that but didn't work. It still aligns to the left.

Comment: "_Yes I tried that but didn't work_" - Please show your attempt by [edit]ing your question and adding the relevant code.

Comment: You can try to modify the [look-and-feel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/index.html) or maybe your operating system's window manager has a setting for centering window titles.

Comment: Create an undecorated JFrame and create your own JPanel that looks like a title bar.

Comment: *Yes I tried that but didn't work* - Works fine for me using JDK11 on Windows 10. If it doesn't work then either 1) you have a version/platform issue or 2) You implemented the suggestion incorrectly. Post your [mre] demonstrating the problem and include your OS and version so people using the same environment can test.